# Changing array values by assigning new array

Tags: c#, memory

I have a bool array

```
private bool[] example =  {false, false};
```

And I change them using a function which also returns true if both values are true.

```
    private bool checkExample(bool firstCondition, bool secondCondition){
        example = new bool[]{firstCondition, secondCondition};
        return example.All(x => x);
    }
```

I am worried about the memory here. Is it  safe changing the array by allocating a new array? `new bool[]{firstCondition, secondCondition};`

What really happens under the hood? From my understanding, since it's inside a function, we're using short term storage? Or because we're using the keyword `new` we're using long term storage?

I highly value your help.

Example use case:

```
checkExample(example[0], true); // and vice versa
```

Comment: Why are you using an array at all? Why not just `return firstCondition && secondCondition;`?

Comment: @gabriel-luci I need to save their state in the array so that it can be shared among many observables. These observables are not connected to each other directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is quite simple.  First you need to realize that all arrays (even arrays of a value type (like `bool`) are instances of a reference type.  So, when you say:

```
private bool[] example =  {false, false};
```

what you are doing is creating a field in your class that contains a reference to a singly dimensioned array of `bool`.  Since you are initializing it, the array is created and initialized, creating an object on the managed heap.

In your method, you are then doing this:

```
example = new bool[]{firstCondition, secondCondition};
```

In that code, you are referring to the that same `example` member as you initialized.  What happens in that code is that a new array of bool is created on the *managed heap* and initialized, and you are assigning to the `example` field a reference to that new array.

At that point, unless you assigned a reference to that original array to something else (a long-lived variable, a field or a property), the original array no longer has any references to it.  Once an object on the managed heap no longer has any references to it, it becomes *eligible for garbage collection*.

At some point in the future, the garbage collector will come by and "collect" the memory.  If the array hadn't been around very long, then it will be collected in a Gen0 collection (which is pretty cheap).  In all likelihood, it will be collected in a Gen1 or Gen2 collection (each of which costs more).

In general, you shouldn't need to worry about things like this.  A managed (/garbage collected) system expects that your code will produce garbage.  Allocation in .NET is very cheap.  Lots of effort goes into making garbage collection (particularly of small objects) efficient.

Comment: If you follow @Serge's suggestion in another answer, you end up with with basically the same result without creating any garbage.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use this,  if you don't need to create a new array  for some another reasons

```
 private bool checkExample(bool firstCondition, bool secondCondition){
        example[0]=firstCondition; 
        example[1]= secondCondition;
        return example.All(x => x);
    }
```

Comment: Good idea, thank you